# Connect signal to signal

Tags: qt-creator, signals-slots, qt-designer

The Qt documentation explicitly states it's possible to connect signals to other signals.

I want to connect a signal to another signal in Qt Creator/Designer (Qt 5.x).

Is this possible via the Qt Creator/Designer UI? If so, how do I do it?

If I *must* write code to create a slot that 'forwards' to another signal to emulate signal->signal connection behavior, is there any way to embed that information in the generated output via the Qt Creator/Designer UI (either as code or otherwise)?

If the answer to the above is an overall 'no', what would be the best way to request this as a feature?